# How do I use asterisk in lookbehind regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, lookbehind

My test string:

```
1. default, no   hair, w/o glass
2. ski suit
3. swim suit
```

How do I detect if there is a "no" or "w/o" before hair (there could be more than 1 spaces in between)?

The final goal:

```
1. default, no   hair, w/o glass    returns False
1. default, no hair, w/o glass    returns False
1. default, w/o hair, w/o glass    returns False
1. default, w hair, w/o glass    returns True
```

The goal is to tell whether glass should be used or not.

My attempt: `(?<!no\s)hair` (http://rubular.com/r/PdKbmyxpGh)

You can see that in the above example, if there are more than 1 space, then my regex won't work.

Comment: How about (?<!no\s)\s+hair

Comment: This simplest way is to not use lookbehinds.  Is there a reason why you can't just match `\b(?:no|w/o)\s+hair\b` and then negate the result?

Answer (score 2):

The `re` module does not support variable length (zero width) look-behind.

You need to either:

- Fixed the number of spaces before `hair`
- Use `regex` module

---

Short function using negative lookahead:

```
def re_check(s):
    return re.search(r'^[^,]+,\s+(?!(?:no|w/o)\s+hair,)', s) is not None

>>> re_check('default, no   hair, w/o glass')
False
>>> re_check('default, w/o hair, w/o glass')
False
>>> re_check('default, w hair, w/o glass')
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

```
data = ['1. default, no   hair, w/o glass',
        '1. default, no hair, w/o glass',
        '1. default, w/o hair, w/o glass',
        '1. default, w hair, w/o glass']

def hair(line):
    result = re.findall('(no|w/o|w)\s+hair', line)
    if result:
        return result[0] == 'w':

[hair(line) for line in data]
```

Output:

```
[False, False, False, True]
```

If the regex finds nothing, `None` is returned.

Comment: Instead of `if ... else ...`, you can simply have `return result[0] == 'w'`

Answer (score 1):

Look behinds do not support variable widths.

Look ahead do support variable width. You can do:

```
^(?!.*(?:(?:\bno\b)|(?:\bw\/o\b)\s+hair))(^.*$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xP5zK6/1)

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is detect where there is a `no` or `w/o` before `hair`, you don't need look-behind (and yes, your pattern is called look-behind, not look-ahead). Just this will do:

```
(?:no|w\/o)\s+hair
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/ySGNIKHM8Z)

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler to check for `w hair`:

```
>>> for line in (
...     '1. default, no   hair, w/o glass',
...     '1. default, no hair, w/o glass',
...     '1. default, w/o hair, w/o glass',
...     '1. default, w hair, w/o glass'
...     ):
...     print(repr(line), bool(re.search(r'w\s+hair', line)))
...
'1. default, no   hair, w/o glass' False
'1. default, no hair, w/o glass' False
'1. default, w/o hair, w/o glass' False
'1. default, w hair, w/o glass' True
```